# Customize server name for error pages in NGINX

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to customize NGINX so when displaying a 500 error page it displays a custom name instead of NGINX?

Similar to what Cloudflare does in some cases by displaying:

```
500 Internal Server Error
------------------------
    cloudflare-nginx
```

My question may seem a bit silly, but if a user of mine indicates it is my server, it presented an error, I can identify whether this actually occurred on our server or during the transit of the request.

Comment: Long time answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246227/how-do-you-change-the-server-header-returned-by-nginx). Or, patch and build your own version of Nginx, as Cloudflare does.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is writing a file ( could be a html ) with your custom page and use this file in `error_page` directive.
Oficial [error_page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) reference.

Something like:

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /my_custom_error.html;
```

And the users will receive this page when got an error.